# In pandas, how can I select the years in the format datetime64 and at the same time the blank lines?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

In python 3 and pandas I have this dataframe:

```
df_comissoes.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 104 entries, 0 to 103
Data columns (total 4 columns):
DataFimComissao    65 non-null datetime64[ns]
IdComissao         104 non-null object
NomeComissao       104 non-null object
SiglaComissao      97 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(3)
memory usage: 3.3+ KB
```

The column "DataFimComissao" has lines with dates or blank (NaT):

```
    index   DataFimComissao     IdComissao  NomeComissao    SiglaComissao
0   0   2008-06-26 03:00:00     11072   CPI da Guerra Fiscal    CPIGF
1   1   2008-06-25 03:00:00     11073   CPI da Queima da Palha da Cana-de-açúcar    CPIQPCA
2   2   2009-04-15 03:00:00     11199   CPI da Santa Casa   CPISC
3   3   NaT                     12769   Comissão Especial de Reforma da Lei Orgânica d...   CERLOM
4   4   NaT                     12770   Comissão do Serviço Público Civil   CSPC
5   5   2010-02-03 02:00:00     12216   CPI do Erro Médico  CPIEM
6   6   2010-10-25 02:00:00     12221   CPI BANCOOP     CPIBANCOOP
7   7   2010-10-06 03:00:00     12222   CPI IPVA    CPIIPVA
8   8   2010-10-25 02:00:00     12223   CPI Pedofilia   CPIPEDOF
9   9   NaT                     12444   Comissão de Constituição, Justiça e Redação     CCJR
```

I need to select only rows with dates "DataFimComissao" with the year equal to or above 2015 or have "NaT"

Please, how can I select the years in the format datetime64[ns] and at the same time the blank lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean mask by chaining [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html)s compared by scalar with check `NaT`s by [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df_comissoes['DataFimComissao'].dt.year >= 2015) | 
       (df_comissoes['DataFimComissao'].isna())
#oldier pandas versions
#mask = (df_comissoes['DataFimComissao'].dt.year >= 2015) | 
#       (df_comissoes['DataFimComissao'].isnull())

df = df_comissoes[mask]
```